# Get pixel data as array from hdc

Tags: c, winapi

I followed this code here to take a screenshot. It puts stuff onto an HDC. I was wondering how to get stuff off from this HDC as an array of pixel data. I want to copy it to clipboard and also draw it to a HTML5 canvas.

Do I have to run `GetPixel` for every point on the HDC, is this the only way to get an array of the bitmap?

```
HBITMAP MakePrintScreen()
{
      HWND hWindow = GetDesktopWindow();
      HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(hWindow);
      RECT rect;
      HBITMAP hbmC;

      GetClientRect(hWindow,&rect);

      if((hbmC = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen,rect.right,rect.bottom)) != NULL)
      {
            HDC hdcC;
            if((hdcC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen)) != NULL)
            {
                  HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcC,hbmC);

                  BitBlt(hdcC,0,0,rect.right,rect.bottom,hdcScreen,0,0,SRCCOPY);

                  SelectObject(hdcC,hbmOld);
                  DeleteDC(hdcC);
            }
      }

      ReleaseDC(hWindow,hdcScreen);

      return hbmC;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you have deselected the bitmap from the device context you call [GetDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the bits from the bitmap.

Comment: Thanks arx can you please work the GetDIBits into the sample code above (i actually do this in js-ctypes so dont know c i just brute convert from c to js-ctypes)